# Hans Saar's thesis

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras, oa.operator-algebras

I would love to have a look on some results which are claimed by some people to be in Saar's thesis:

> H. Saar, *Kompakte, vollständig beschränkte Abbildungen mit Werten in einer nuklearen C${}^\ast$-Algebra*, Diplomarbeit, Universität des Saarlandes, Saarbrücken, 1982.

Unfortunately, I cannot localize the mathematician named H. Saar (in particular, the Math Genealogy Project gives no outputs).

I would appreciate any help with finding his thesis.

EDIT: **quid** is quite right. The Universität des Saarlandes Library lists it as Master's thesis. If you google for it, then you'll see it is pretty frequently cited and it is very unusual (ar least in my opinion) for a Master's thesis to have such impact.

Comment: Searching for 'Saar' in the catalogue of the relevant library http://www.infomath-bib.de/en/welcome.shtml gives an entry for the document. In principle it seems feasible to get it (or a copy) via some interlibrary loan from there; or by asking someone there. 
 
Sideremark: this is not (the analog of) a PhD thesis; more like a master or senior thesis. It is thus unsurprsing it is not in Math Genealogy database.